# How can I get updated row from MySQL in wordpress site?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to display the time and date of updated row from MySQL to wordpress site.  How can I do that?

Comment: Please explain in brief what exactly you want to do ?

Comment: i want to display updated row from mysql in php

Comment: what's `updated row`? try to provide some context to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Modified Date: <?php the_modified_date('F j, Y'); ?> at <?php the_modified_date('g:i a'); ?>
```

Using this function you can get modified date

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that you want to display the date/time the post was modified, have a look at the link below.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_modified_date#Date_and_Time

```
// Displays the date and time.

<p>Modified: <?php the_modified_date('F j, Y'); ?> at <?php the_modified_date('g:i a'); ?></p>

// Modified: December 2, 2006 at 10:36 pm
```